KEDA starting too many replicas
I'm trying to use KEDA (v2.15) in my AKS cluster.  I have it installed and the ClusterTriggerAuth configured.
# Source: reader-job/templates/scaled-job.yaml
# https://keda.sh/docs/2.15/concepts/scaling-jobs/
# https://keda.sh/docs/2.15/reference/scaledjob-spec/
# https://keda.sh/docs/2.15/scalers/azure-service-bus/
apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1
kind: ScaledJob
metadata:
  name: my-job
  namespace: dev
  annotations:
    autoscaling.keda.sh/paused: "false"
spec:
  jobTargetRef:
    parallelism: 1
    completions: 1
    backoffLimit: 0
    activeDeadlineSeconds: 600
    template:
      spec:
        containers:
          - name: main
            image: ....
            imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
            resources:
              limits:
                memory: "4Gi"
              requests:
                memory: "1.5Gi"
                cpu: "1"
          - name: sidecar
            image: ....
            imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
            resources:
              limits:
                memory: "2Gi"
              requests:
                memory: "512Mi"
                cpu: "100m"
        restartPolicy: Never
  pollingInterval: 10
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 10
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 10
  minReplicaCount: 0
  maxReplicaCount: 3
  scalingStrategy:
    strategy: accurate # tried default and eager as well
  triggers:
    - type: azure-servicebus
      metadata:
        queueName: // the name of my queue in SB
        messageCount: "1" // start a job for every message in the queue
      authenticationRef:
        name: dev-cluster-trigger-auth
        kind: ClusterTriggerAuthentication

when I put a message in the queue, KEDA pretty much immediately starts three jobs.  One of them actually does some work....the other two just sit completely idle and do nothing because "there is no message in the queue".
Why would KEDA start three jobs when the queue only had one message?
I've scoured the docs and don't see anything I've missed.  I've also tried default, accurate and eager scale settings.  Pretty much the same behavior across the board.
is this behavior expected?  I feel like I may be misunderstanding something

What do you mean "pretty much immediately"? (Is it just starting a new job every 10s until it reaches max replicas, because the first job takes too long to start up and remove the message from the queue?)

no....I mean I immediately get three jobs running when only one message was added to the queue. The container uses auto lock renewing to keep locking the message while processing.  Why would one message in the queue trigger three jobs?

It might be helpful to post the keda operator logs.

If the worker sits idle (rather than exiting) when there is no work in the queue, you could also consider scaling a deployment rather than using jobs.

that's the exact reason I'm trying to use ScaledJob.  I don't want any workers running until there are messages in the queue.  for every message, a job should be started that runs to completion.
